# How to prevent triggering the error event on window when error is caught by error boundary?

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

Is there a way to prevent triggering the `error` event on the `window` when the React error boundary catches the error?

By now, the error is caught by the error boundary and `error` event on the `window`.

In other words, when an error is caught by the error boundary, the error handling code in `window.onerror` should not be executed.

`App.tsx`:

```
import "./styles.css";
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ErrorComponent = () => {
  const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (showError) JSON.parse("");
  }, [showError]);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setShowError(true);
      }}
    >
      JSON parse SyntaxError
    </button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleError = () => {
      console.log("Please contact the sale. 888-888-888");
    };

    window.addEventListener("error", handleError);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("error", handleError);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <ErrorComponent />
      </div>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}
```

`ErrorBoundary.tsx`:

```js
import React from "react";

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  public static getDerivedStateFromError(error: any) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  public render() {
    const { hasError } = this.state;
    console.log("hasError: ", hasError);
    if (hasError) {
      return <div>Something went wrong</div>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lucid-cerf-d5xggq?file=%2Fsrc%2FErrorBoundary.tsx%3A10%2C38&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpcdntw200073j6iuem7okqe%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpcdntw200033j6iz9nvoj8e%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpcdntw200043j6ikbi980eg%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpcdntw200063j6ii4pxrw6a%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpcdntw200033j6iz9nvoj8e%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpcdntw200033j6iz9nvoj8e%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpcdvnjz00033j6id3rnkt2l%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A9%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A6%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A9%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A6%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpce8xyg00033j6ikvy73k3b%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A10%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A38%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A10%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A38%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FErrorBoundary.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpce8xyg00033j6ikvy73k3b%2522%257D%252C%2522clpcdntw200063j6ii4pxrw6a%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpcdntw200063j6ii4pxrw6a%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpcdntw200053j6i5ja2k0zm%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpcdntw200053j6i5ja2k0zm%2522%257D%252C%2522clpcdntw200043j6ikbi980eg%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpcdntw200043j6ikbi980eg%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)